# How to properly compile html form data into JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which collects some information (asset cost, asset description, shareholders, and how much each of the shareholders own). I want to compile all this information in a JSON object and post it. When I collect the data and JSON.stringify() it, it looks like this:

```
[ { name: '1', value: '50' },
{ name: 'asset_desc', value: 'boat' },
{ name: 'asset_cost', value: '100' },
{ name: 'org_id', value: '2' },
{ name: '3', value: '50' },
{ name: 'asset_desc', value: 'boat' },
{ name: 'asset_cost', value: '100' },
{ name: 'org_id', value: '2' } ]
```

I want to clean this data up before posting so it looks like this:

```
{
    "asset_desc": "boat",
    "asset_cost": "100",
    "org_id": 2,
    "share_holders": {
        "1": "50",
        "2": "50"
    }
}
```

I am running jQuery. Does jQuery have some built-in helpers that would make the cleaning up of this data simple? The function I'm using to get the data like this in the first place is:

```
formdata = $('#addpurchaseform');
data = JSON.stringify(formdata.serializeArray());
```

Is there a better way to do this so that my data is in a cleaner state? Am I even thinking about this correctly (I am new to web development)?

Not sure if this matters, but the receiving end of this is Python / Django so I figured it would be better if I sent a clean JSON object rather than trying to parse / clean the mess after it was received.

Comment: There is no way a 3rd party library will know what you mean by "a clean JSON object" since "clean" is just your subjective preference. You have to change the structure of your object with your own code.

Comment: I never said or assumed there would be. I asked if there was a jQuery library that would make it easier for me to clean this data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a jQuery plugin, then try this:
https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON